# Regex to match URL that does not begin with string in WP Redirection plugin

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, redirect

Currently, I'm using Redirection plugin in WordPress to redirect all URLs that contain q question mark in this way:

```
Source: /(.*)\?(.*)$
Target: /$1
```

This works well. It will redirect any link with a `?`, such as `/good-friends-are-great.html?param=x` to `/good-friends-are-great.html`.

However, now I need to make an exception. I need to allow `/friends` to pass GET parameters, e.g. `/friends?guest=1&event=chill_out&submit=2` OR `/friends/?more_params`, without the parameters being truncated.

I have tried modifying the regular expression in the plugin to:

```
Source: /(?!friends/?)\?(.*)$
Target: /$1
```

But this didn't work. With the above expression, any link with `?` is no longer redirected.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expressions below:

```
/(.*(?<!friends)(?<!friends/))\?.*$
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT2yS9/1)

The regex is using 2 negative look-behinds because in this regex flavor, we cannot use variable-width look-behinds. `(.*(?<!friends)(?<!friends/))` matches any number of any characters up to `?`, but checks if the `?` is not preceded with either `friends` or `friends/`.

**EDIT:**

Here is my first regex that did not work well for the current scenario:

```
/((?:(?!friends/?).)+)\?.*$
```

Its subpattern `(?:(?!friends/?).)+` matches a string that does not contain `friends` or `friends/`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! The first answer is very close but it failed on 1 occasion: 1) `/friends-are-good.html?param` where param refers to any GET parameters appended after `?`. The parameter in 1) should be truncated, but it is not. But the second answer satisfied all conditions!

Comment: I have removed the faulty suggestion, and added explanation to the one that worked.

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation (I was about to ask)! Actually, you could have leave the first answer intact as it is useful for people like me to understand regex better.

Comment: I put the first regex back into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the first `(.*)`, you should have just added to it:

```
Source: /(?!friends/?)(.*)\?(.*)$
Target: /$1
```

The negative look-ahead group `(?!friends/?)` doesn't match anything by itself; it just prevents certain matches.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! The answer is close but it failed on 2 occasions: 1) `/friends-are-good.html?param` and 2) `/friends/?param` where param refers to any GET parameters appended after `?`. The parameter in 1) should be truncated, but it is not. The parameter in 2) should not be truncated, but it is. So sorry if my question was not clear enough.